# Fallo al usar una función lambda dentro de una conexión SIGNAL/SLOT

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy intentando dotar a una tabla de un comportamiento concreto, que sería que al seleccionar una celda y arrastrar el ratón solamente seleccionara las celdas de la misma columna. 
Para ello, y mirando cuestiones [similares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272543/qtableview-limit-number-of-selected-items) he intentado usar una función lambda.

La cosa, y aquí viene la duda, es que si hago la conexión entre la selección y la función fuera del constructor de la tabla, no tengo problemas, pero si lo intento hacer dentro del constructor, me da este error:
`QObject::connect: invalid null parameter`

En concreto, esto me funciona:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    MiTabla *tabla = new MiTabla;    
    tabla->setModel(new MiModelo());
    tabla->setItemDelegate(new MiDelegado());
    selectionModel = tabla->selectionModel();
    setCentralWidget(tabla);
    QObject::connect(selectionModel,&QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,[=]()
    {
        foreach (const QModelIndex& item, selectionModel->selectedIndexes())
        {
            if (item.column()!=tabla->indiceActual().column())
            {
                selectionModel->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Pero esto me da el error antes comentado:

```
MiTabla::MiTabla()
{
    miSelectionModel = selectionModel();        
    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(pressed(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(CambiarIndiceACtual(QModelIndex)));

    QObject::connect(miSelectionModel,&QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,[=]()
    {
        foreach (const QModelIndex& item, miSelectionModel->selectedIndexes())
        {
            if (item.column()!=m_indiceActual.column())
            {
                miSelectionModel->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cuál de todos los `connect` es el que falla?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, es el segundo, el que hace uso de la función lambda. El caso es que equivoqué y al principio mandé la pregunta a stackoverflow. Después de recibir las collejas correspondientes por preguntar en español allí, y una vez traducida, ya me han dado la solución. El problema es que al intentar establecer la conexión en el constructor de la tabla, no tenía un modelo asignado. Sin embargo, al hacerlo fuera de la tabla, ya sí existe ese modelo. Vamos, que estoy empanao...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si echamos un vistazo a [este enlace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) vemos que cada vez que se llama a `setModel` se crea un nuevo `QItemSelectionModel`. ¿Y qué pasa con el anterior? Pues como resulta que el padre es la propia tabla, el objeto se destruye sin más miramientos.

```
class MiTabla
{
public:
  MiTabla()
  {
    miSelectionModel = selectionModel(); // Copia del puntero...

    QObject::connect(miSelectionModel,&QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,[=]()
    {
      foreach (const QModelIndex& item, miSelectionModel->selectedIndexes()) // <<--- usas la copia
      {
        if (item.column()!=m_indiceActual.column())
        {
          miSelectionModel->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect); // <<--- aqui también
        }
      }
    });

private:
  QItemSelectionModel* miSelectionModel;
};

MiTabla *tabla = new MiTabla;    // Aqui se inicializa miSelectionModel
tabla->setModel(new MiModelo()); // Aqui se crea un nuevo selectionModel(),
                                 // miSelectionModel apunta a algo que no es válido
```

Entonces, si resulta que la lambda almacena **una copia** de un puntero a un `QItemSelectionModel` que ya ha sido borrado el resultado no puede ser positivo de ninguna manera.

No hay absolutamente ningún motivo que justifique la necesidad de duplicar el puntero `selectionModel`. Pedirlo dentro de la lambda te ahorrará disgustos:

```
QObject::connect(miSelectionModel,&QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, [this]()
{
  auto miSelectionModel = selectionModel();  
  for( QModelIndex const& item : miSelectionModel->selectedIndexes() )
  {
    if( item->column() != m_indiceActual.column() )
    {
      miSelectionModel->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
    }
  }
});
```

Aunque lo cierto es que no hay necesidad de usar lambdas. Un pequeño problema de usar lambdas aquí es que las mismas no se pueden desconectar posteriormente, lo que te puede dar problemas en el futuro. Es más práctico crear un slot en `MiTabla`:

```
class MiTabla
{
private slots:

  void SelectionChanged()
  {
    auto miSelectionModel = selectionModel();  
    for( QModelIndex const& item : miSelectionModel->selectedIndexes() )
    {
      if( item->column() != m_indiceActual.column() )
      {
        miSelectionModel->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Gracias por los apuntes. La cosa es que el puntero es de esas cosas que tenía en mente quitar por su inutilidad (no había previsto la verdad los otros problemas que me describes). Por completar la respuesta por si la quieres editar, te has comido los paréntesis en el último ```selectionModel``` y el nombre después del ```auto``` da error por similitud con la función :-). Y como off-topic, pensaba que esto era un error: ```for( QModelIndex const& item...``` y veo que está bien escrito. (Pensaba que querías haber puesto ```for(const  QModelIndex & item...```)

Comment: @user3733164 cierto, gracias por el apunte. Si, las variables se pueden declarar también así, poniendo los modificadores después del tipo. A mi personalmente me parce más limpio ya que el tipo se queda al principio y los modificadores detrás y no en plan popurrí ( en `const QModelIndex &` tanto `const` como `&` son modificadores del tipo `QModelIndex`). Lo del error de similitud con la función ha sido por darle un nombre diferente al de tu variable miembro para evitar errores de copypaste

Comment: siempre se aprende algo nuevo. No tenía ni idea de que el ```const``` se podía poner de esa forma!