# ¿Como cambiar el comportamiento del ratón sobre una tabla según la zona en la que actúe?

Tags: c++, qt

Esta duda tiene relación con [esta previa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267428/fallo-al-usar-una-funci%C3%B3n-lambda-dentro-de-una-conexi%C3%B3n-signal-slot), dentro del intento de darle a una tabla un comportamiento específico. Lo que quiero es que la tabla actúe de forma parecida a una hoja de cálculo, de forma que si arrastro una celda desde un punto cualquiera de ella, se limite a seleccionar las celdas que sean, pero si hago ese arrastre desde un punto concreto, el contenido de las celdas seleccionadas se modifique en función de la primera. Como bonus (ver el enlace primero) la selección estaría restringida a las celdas de la misma columna.

Para la representación gráfica del área seleccionado, he seguido [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515695/qt-qtableview-draw-border-around-active-cells), siendo ésta mi implementación:

```
void MiTabla::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QTableView::paintEvent(event);

       if(!selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size()>0)
           return;
       //area que engloba a todas las celdas seleccionadas
       QRect rect = visualRect(selectedIndexes().first()) |
              visualRect(selectedIndexes().last());
       QPen pen(Qt::black, 2);
       QPainter painter(viewport());
       painter.setPen(pen);
       painter.drawRect(rect);
       //pequeño boton en la parte inferior derecha del rectángulo de selección
       painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black)));
       painter.drawRect(rect.x()+rect.width()-5,rect.y()+rect.height()-5,5,5);
       viewport()->update();
}
```

Esto crea un rectángulo alrededor de todas las celdas seleccionadas, y un pequeño cuadrado en la parte inferior derecha del rectángulo.

Ahora viene lo difícil:
Al pasar el ratón por la celda, y estar ésta seleccionada, el puntero debería de cambiar de forma para indicar que se puede hacer el arrastre. Y además este arrastre debería restringir la selección a los elementos de la misma columna y llamar a una función específica (para esta última parte no debo de tener problemas), pero si se arrastra desde fuera de la pequeña marca simplemente se ejecutaría la selección típica de una tabla sin más consecuencias, restricciones o llamadas a funciones.

Para el cambio de puntero, estaba intentando esto, pero me anula la visualización de la selección:

```
void MiTabla::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    QModelIndex index = indexAt(pos);
    if (index.isValid() && index == m_indiceActual)
    {
        if (index.column() == m_indiceActual.column())
        {
            QRect rect = this->visualRect(index);
            if (pos.x()>rect.x()+rect.width()-5 && pos.y()>rect.y()-5)
            {
                setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);                    
            }
            else
            {
                setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        CambiarIndiceACtual(index);
    }
    QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Y ahora la pregunta: ¿Como establecer que según se pulse y arrastre con el ratón dentro de una celda, actúe de una forma normal o específica, según si presiono en un área concreta de ella?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pues ha costado pero parece que he conseguido una solución que funciona. Otra cosa es que el código tenga sus sombras, pero le he dado muchas vueltas y no sé hacerlo mejor.

Lo más importante del mismo es el filtro de eventos, que maneja el evento `QEvent::HoverMove` que -creo- no puede manejar la propia tabla. Este se encarga de cambiar el tipo de cursor para que aparezca una cruceta o desaparezca según se pase por la marca que hay en la zona inferior derecha de la selección. También cambia el modo de selección que cambiará el comportamiento de la selección de la tabla, restringiendo dicha selección a solo las celdas que comparten columna con la primera seleccionada. Además al soltar el ratón en este modo de selección se ejecutará una acción. Si no, se hará una selección normal.

Este es el código:

```
bool MyEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if( event->type() == QEvent::HoverMove)
    {
        QHoverEvent * hoverEvent = static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(event);
        QPoint pos = table->viewport()->mapFromParent(hoverEvent->pos());
        //establecer puntero del raton
        if (table->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size()>0)//si hay alguna celda seleccionada
        {
            QRect rectSelect = table->visualRect(table->selectionModel()->currentIndex());

            if (pos.x()>=rectSelect.bottomRight().x()-table->LeeTamMarca() &&
                    pos.x()<=rectSelect.bottomRight().x() &&
                    pos.y()>=rectSelect.bottomRight().y()-table->LeeTamMarca() &&
                    pos.y()<=rectSelect.bottomRight().y())
            {
                if (!table->BotonIzquierdoPresionado())
                {
                    table->setCursor(Qt::CrossCursor);
                    table->SetModoSeleccionRestringido();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                table->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
                if (!table->BotonIzquierdoPresionado())
                {
                    table->SetModoSeleccionNormal();
                }
            }
        }
        //boton en la tercera columna
        currentIndex = table->indexAt(pos);
        QRect rect = table->visualRect(currentIndex);
        button->setVisible(currentIndex.isValid() && currentIndex.column() == 3);

        if( button->isVisible() )
        {
            QPoint point = rect.topRight();
            point.setX(point.x() - button->width());
            button->move(table->viewport()->mapToParent(point));
        }
        event->accept();
        return true;
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)//quito la cruceta del puntero
    {
        table->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        //retorno false para propagar el evento a la tabla y que la funcion tabla::mouseReleaseEvent termine de hacer otras cosas
        //esta misma función, de hacer que el puntero vuelva al modo "arrow", podría hacerse desde la tabla, pero la dejo aquí
        //por legibilidad, ya que las funciones que cambian el modo del cursor estan aqui
        return false;
    }   
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

A su vez la tabla maneja los eventos de `mousePressEvent()`y `mouseReleaseEvent()` los cuales cambiarán el modo de selección y manejan la variable booleana `m_BotonIzqPresionado` la cual también condiciona el comportamiento del filtro de eventos.

En fin, todo el código es muy mejorable y creo que sobran cosas, pero por ahora funciona. Si alguien lo quiere consultar está aquí:
https://github.com/exodehm/tablacalc